# How to implement a CSS template on JSF

Tags: java, css, netbeans

I´m working on a web application on java netbeans and for the graphic interface I want to implement a CSS template, yet I don´t how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by _implement a CSS template_

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new file with css extension and in xhtml you add

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/myFile.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're a little lost here and don't know where to start. This is not even a doubt or a question, but ake a look at this:

https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/

May be a beginning.